# How can l make a website mobile friendly?

Tags: responsive

I want to make my website mobile friendly. But I  don't know  how.

What should I do?
Please tell me. What code I should write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BootStrap. This is the basic package.
Please see the url https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/.
And use appropriate tags to activate bootstrap library.

Syntax for mobile friendly structure in html page after activation of bs library.

```
<div class='row'>
 <div class='col-md-3'> column 1 </div>
 <div class='col-md-3'> column 2 </div>
 <div class='col-md-3'> column 3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I heard about media queries . Can I use media queries instead of bootstrap for making my website responsive.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804977/whats-the-difference-between-media-queries-and-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of information out there on how to do that. A quick Google search will show you various options.

Bootstrap for one is a very popular framework to make your website responsive. Have a look at that. There are other frameworks like Bootstrap as well like Pure.css, Montage.js, Materialize, etc.